# Ensuring a webapp user can only add records to a database that they own

Tags: mysql, database, security, web-applications, relational-database

I am working on a very simple web application to log teachers, students, and homework each in their own table in a MySQL database. A student is assigned to a teacher and a table logs which homework tasks have been completed by which students.

A teacher can select a certain homework task, and then pick one of their students as having completed it. Submitting this will record the student has completed the homework.

The tables look as follows:

Teacher

```
--------------------------
|teacher_id | name       |
--------------------------
|           |            |
```

Student

```
--------------------------
|student_id | teacher_fk |
--------------------------
|           |            |
```

Homework

```
--------------------------
|homework_id | details   |
--------------------------
|            |           |
```

Homework_completion

```
-------------------------------------------
|completion_id | student_fk | homework_fk |
-------------------------------------------
|              |            |             |
```

When a teacher picks a homework task and a student and submits this as being completed, a MySQL INSERT is used as follows

```
INSERT INTO homework_completion VALUES 'student_id', 'homework_id'
```

Both of these values are retrieved from a form submitted by the user. If a user were to use browser developer tools, they could change the student_id in the form, and then save a homework completion for a student they do not 'own'.

How is best to avoid this? Is there any option better than doing a select before hand to check if the student belongs to the teacher?

Comment: You already gave the answer by yourself. You have to check, if the student belongs to te teacher that submit the request by doing a select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your session, you'll store the id of the teacher (logged in user).

When performing an insert, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to enforce the rule:

```
INSERT INTO homework_completion (student_fk, homework_fk)
  SELECT s.student_id, :homework_id
  FROM student s
  WHERE s.student_id = :student_id
  AND s.teacher_fk = :teacher_id
```

Zero records will be inserted if the student's teacher id doesn't match.

Add `LIMIT 1` to the select clause if there's a chance of duplicate records in `student` for a particular student and teacher.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind but didn't know the syntax - thanks